# NGINX | HHVM | PHP - Unable to require anything but .txt files

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I've setup HHVM & NGINX on my local machine, and it works perfectly without any problems. Last day I did it on my Ubuntu VPS, but with alot of errors, which mostly has been fixed, but the one I am unable to resolve is this one:

`Fatal error: require_once(/usr/share/nginx/html/app/interfaces/interface.core.php): File not found in /usr/share/nginx/html/global.php`
Now the issue is, that the path and file does exist, but this only works if I try to require a **.txt** file, but doesn't work with for example **.xml** neither. I have included the web path inside my **server.ini** file also: 
`included_path = /usr/share/nginx/html`
Other than that, HHVM & NGINX is setup correctly, it just isn't able to handle requires or includes, I don't know why.

[image: As you can see below, when I try to enter the path myself in the web browser, it asks me if I want to download it, but it says file doesn't exists using file_exists()]

Comment: It really does sound like the file is not found as oppose to not being read correctly. Are you sure the file is there. If you change the extension on `interface.core.php` to `interface.core.txt` and then require that file does it load correctly? It's crucial that you change this file for now to prove out that the path exists and the extension is the problem.

Comment: You're right it didn't require it as you wrote, but it did in `/usr/share/html` folder, could it have something to do with folder permissions?

Comment: Possibly but I would think PHP should have access to it in a typical installation. If you navigate to the folder that can be found `/usr/share/nginx/html` is there an `app` folder that contains an `interfaces` folder and the php file? What does calling `echo realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); exit;` show if added to `global.php`.

Comment: There is, and I tried adding the code you just wrote, and it outputs `/usr/share/nginx/html` as supposed to

Comment: Hmm, this is really strange. I apologize but I'm beginning to run out of ideas. Perhaps check to see that the `interfaces` folder is plural and not `interface`?

Comment: Every code is checked, because I've .zipped this from many servers and system, and it works on every single one except for this, and no code has been edited, I even used this on my own Ubuntu OS with NGINX & HHVM, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Added a screenshot in question.

Comment: But if I move it to the root folder of the webserver, it says it exists, like wtf.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some research, I found out I had to chown the root folder of my webserver, but it didn't work with `/usr/share/nginx/html`.
 I had to move my files to `/var/www/html` and change the root folder, then I used this to grant entire folder permission access. 
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html`